# ggplot,object 'value' not found in lasso

Tags: r, ggplot2, lasso-regression

I am trying to plot relevant variables for my `PlayStoreLasso` model, but i am getting this error:

> ```
> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'value' not found
> ```

Can you please help me

```r
coef(PlayStoreLasso, s = "lambda.1se") %>%
  tidy() %>%
  filter(row != "(Intercept)") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, reorder(row,value), color = value > 0)) +
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Influential variables") +
  xlab("Coefficient") +
  ylab(NULL)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, though it's a little simpler if you call `tidy` on the model, not the `coef` matrix: `glmnet::glmnet(as.matrix(mtcars[-1]), mtcars[[1]], alpha = 1) %>% broom::tidy() %>% filter(term != '(Intercept)') %>% ggplot(aes(estimate, reorder(term, estimate), color = estimate > 0)) + geom_point()`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. I got these two warning messages: Warning messages:
1: 'tidy.dgCMatrix' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated") 
2: 'tidy.dgTMatrix' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated")    can you please tell me if they are expected?

Comment: Those are left over from calling `tidy` on the coefficients. Calling `tidy` on the model shouldn't give you those warnings, because there's a `tidy.glmnet` method that gets called instead.

Comment: I have already made lasso model, so if i put my model PlayStoreLasso instead of mtcars i get this error: Error in glmnet::glmnet(as.matrix(PlayStoreLasso[-1]), PlayStoreLasso[[1]],  : 
  x should be a matrix with 2 or more columns

Comment: The `glmnet` call was an example model. Put your model directly into `tidy`.